# What is the exact reason of using sign convention to derive mirror formula & if it's done already then why sign convention is used again for problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, geometric-optics

Today i studied about mirror formula, its derivation and sign convention used while deriving it, a question which i have is, why do i have to use sign convention while doing the derivation ? focal length, object and image distance all are distance so what is the point of using sign convention ? and while solving problems based on mirror formula why we use the sign convention again ? I have seen some answers on internet, they say that we use sign convention two times to cancel the effect of sign convention, but if want to cancel the effect of sign convention in the end then why do we use it, can't we solve without it ?

Comment: Have you checked the possible duplicates, because this question is already asked multiple times

Comment: @Peterswift Yeah i have, but they are saying we did that to cancel the effect of sign convention but that doesn't make a point

Comment: because with an appropriate sign convention *all* formulas for any kind of lenses and mirrors have the same form.

Comment: Finally i got the answer, which satisfies me : https://youtu.be/roFZmWAzQfc?feature=shared